# Swagger `Unable to autoload constant`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

Swagger docs are failing to build, with the error:

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant ThingsController, expected /path/to/my/app/controllers/api/things_controller.rb to define it
```

The weird thing is, the class **is** defined there, and the app is working: only swagger fails.

`things_controller.rb` contains

```
class Api::ThingsController < ActionController::Base
  swagger_controller :things, "Things"

  swagger_api :index do
    summary "Returns list of things"
  end
end
```

Any ideas why Swagger would be unable to find a functioning class in the file where it is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had a very strange conclusion: there are two `ThingsController`s, one in the API namespace, `Api::ThingsController` and one in the base namespace `ThingsController`. The one in the base namespace was removed but was still referred to by the `routes.rb`, which was a bug in the codebase.

The error being reported was that it couldn't find `Api::ThingsController` in `/path/to/my/app/controllers/api/things_controller.rb` **but instead** it was failing to find `ThingsController` in `/path/to/my/app/controllers/things_controller.rb`.

My conclusion is that there is a bug in Rails error reporting in the lazy loader. It reports the wrong error. **If you get a nonsensical message, check that there isn't a name clash**.

I think this is unrelated to Swagger, but triggered by it because (I guess) it spiders the source tree looking for Swagger annotations.

Answer (score 0):

By convention in rails (and this is enforced by autoloader), file paths should match namespaces

Additionally, you probably have autoloader kicking in when trying to load a things_controller class (my guess is that it happens from within Act things_controller). It looks for a things_controller.rb file in load path, find it in app/controller/ and thus load that file so it can find the ThingsController class.

it should be in app/controller/things_controller.rb.

```
class ThingsController < ActionController::Base
  swagger_controller :things, "Things"

  swagger_api :index do
    summary "Returns list of things"
  end
end
```

Refer this link (https://coderwall.com/p/bjk3pa/documenting-rails-based-rest-api-using-swagger-ui)

Comment: I'm trying to understand your comment. When you say `app/controller/` I assume you mean `app/controllers/`? If so, the path of the file **is** correct, surely? The error message points to the existing file, which, as I said **does** contain the class.